# How can you determine if webapp2 called your function or if it was another method in Python?

Tags: python, webapp2

I have a a route that is defined like this:

```
webapp2.Route(r'/test/<var1>', handler="handlers.Test.test", methods="GET")
```

the handler looks like this:

```
def test(self, var1=None):
```

when I call it from a url such as (Case A):

```
http://localhost:8080/test/helloworld
```

I get the variable

```
var1=helloworld
```

which is pretty cool. Now lets say instead of calling it from a URL I instead want to call it from another function ala (Case B):

```
def calltest(self):
    self.test(helloworld)
```

How can I determine that in case A it's being called from the webapp2 Route and in case B I can tell it's being called from another function with the app itself?

The why of this in case A I want to return JSON since the browser doesn't speak Python and in case B I want to return an object since the calling function is itself in Python so it can understand that return type.

As a possible side note this is my attempt at getting double use of the same method, this is somewhat what I suppose something like Endpoints is trying to achieve, but it seems easy enough this way as well if I can case the return based in the caller.

Thanks!

Shaun

Comment: Just add another function that wraps the result of `handlers.Test.test` and call that from your route instead.

Comment: That's kind of counter to what I'm trying to accomplish, having a bunch of methods that do the exact same thing, but one is simply for a different entrance path, i.e. webapp2 versus not seems a little silly. Over time that's a lot of extra methods that really don't do much.

Comment: [Setting a custom dispatcher](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/handlers.html#guide-handlers-returned-values) looks promising

Comment: Not sure how that would work in my case, sample code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with webapp2, but something like the following might work:

```
def test(var1=None):
    return { var1: var1 }


def calltest():
    d = test()
    print(d['var1'])


def disp(router, request, response):
    rv = router.default_dispatcher(request, response)
    # turn dict into json and craft the response
    return webapp2.Response(json.dumps(rv))
    # alternatively, you could make your handlers return objects with a .json()
    # method and call that


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    webapp2.Route(r'/test/<var1>', handler=test, methods="GET"),
])

app.router.set_dispatcher(disp)
```

Comment: But how is it returning a python object in the case where calltest() is being called versus json when test() is called from a route? Sorry if I'm being dense, thanks!

Comment: `disp` is responsible for converting the result of `test` to json and will automatically be called from the route. This will also work with multiple routes, you just have to make sure `disp` can handle the results of your handlers.

Comment: So in the case where I just call calltest() the custom dispatcher won't be called so I can just return a standard value or object in that instance and it will work fine? That's pretty cool!

Comment: As long as it is something `disp` knows how to turn into json, yes.